# How to Implement SSL in XAMPP

Tags: ssl, xampp

I have a website built with Dream Weaver and XAMPP.  I want my site to be secure, so I want to implement SSL on my site.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

ssl is a server concept, not an application/service concept. It looks like xampp uses an Apache webserver, so this document should get you started.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html

here is a doc specific to xampp's apache installation:
http://www.leoganda.net/how-to-enable-xampp-ssl-socket-transport/